Potential Transistor Substitute for 2SB984K
This BJT is non-existent and seemingly hard to find a replacement.

I have some of these on-hand:
https://www.onsemi.cn/pdf/datasheet/ksa992-d.pdf
It seems to be up to the task, generally speaking, but it's hFE ratings are stated at -6V and the original part is stated at -1V. Does that imply that the KSA992 will not function similarly below -6V?
Thanks.
This is the area of the schematic:

This is the Full Datasheet of the original BJT.

hFE drops as the |Vce| drops close to saturation, so ones specified at -1V are at least as good as ones specified at -6V, all other things being equal.
Depending on the beta bin the ones you have may be out of spec for hFE being too high (by as much as 50%), but the circuit would have to be a bit odd for that to cause problems.
Woah- thanks for the full datasheet -the maximum IC of the original part is 1A vs. 50mA for the KSA992! They are in no way a general substitute. These guys seem to have it with reasonable shipping (have not heard of them though).
Just for fun I compared hFE of the 2SAR375P5 at -1V vs -6V and got 123 vs. 148. About 17% less at 1V, so not a huge drop.

"ones specified at -1V are at least as good as ones specified at -6V, all other things being equal" -does that mean that I can use the -6V part to sub? it sounds like you are saying I could use a -1V part in place of the -6V part, but maybe not the other way around?

@vol.2 Yes, that's correct. Could it be an issue? Depends on the circuit details. If you can find a SPICE model you could compare typical hFE at -1V vs. -6V. One definitely exists for the B984. I suspect it's an okay subsitute.

I've never used SPICE before. I see there's one called LT SPICE I could use. Is this something I could just show the transistor in, or would I have to build the whole schematic? It's a huge schematic (the small area that this transistor is in it in my post above).

If you're just measuring the transistor hFE you only need to simulate the transistor, a current source and a 1V voltage source. But you would need to find the transistor model and install it, which can be a bit arcane.

The 2SB984 is apparently in Orcad SPICE, but doesn't appear in the regular LTSPICE libraries. I found this post with a guy that made some addition libraries available, but not sure if it'll be in there yet. Still trying to figure out how to install extra libraries.

See my note about the maximum Ic. It's 20x lower than the original!

Thank YOU! I will not try! I have a ZTX751 coming from Digikey, I think that it will do, and I am able to also get the NPN version. I thought maybe it was best to replace the pair. https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/115/ztx750-1165283.pdf
